# Function to search List of items

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create function which search the cell value in the list of items and provide the result, I wrote two codes but none of them working.

**1st Code:**

```
Function MneLookup(vCell As Variant)

Rng = "C:\user\TestFolder\[List of Items.xlsx]Mnem list'!SA$1:$C$5000"

     MneLookup =Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(vCell, Range(rng), 3, False)

End Function
```

**2nd Code:**

```
Function MneLookup(vCell As Variant)

vPath = "C:\user\TestFolder\[List of Items.xlsx]Mnem list'!"
vAddress = "SA$1:$C$5000"

     MneLookup =Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(vCell, vPath & Range(vAddress), 3, False)

End Function
```

Further, if there is another more efficient way to do that it would be great other than Vlookup function.

Comment: The book must be open and a UDF cannot open a workbook

Comment: Not sure if you could utilize `ExcecuteExcel4Macro` within an UDF, but if you don't want to open a seperate workbook you could look into it.

Comment: As @urdearboy noted above, you'll need to write a subroutine. Your best route would be to load the range into an array and loop through the array. It'll be much faster than a VLOOKUP.